# Python ImageMagick Shepard's Distortion

Tags: python, image, import, warp

I'm currently writing a script to map an image onto a mug for mock-up purposes.
The whole idea is to take away dependence on Photoshop so we can bulk automate this process. However, due to the shape of a mug, the images have to be warped to look correct.
I had a quick look online, and I found [this article](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards) on the subject, and it really isn't too learner-friendly. I've gotten all the co-ordinates I *think* I need for this to work, I'm just not too sure on how to input the data.
I laid out my code in this way to make it easier for me to access (in my mind at least) and modify on a whim. However, I can't seem to work out how to actually *use* the Shepards Distortion via ImageMagick. I've tried to import a short list of ImageMagick and MagickWand variants, but they all return "ImportError: No Module named x", which is the first problem. Once I get past that point, I'm not even sure that the code I have will actually work. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would really *really* appreciate it.

```
MUG_SIDE = [[428,615,1221,1609],[".../mug-side.png"],[[0,0,499,44],[2100,0,2098,390],[4200,0,3784,175],[0,4800,606,3911],[2100,4800,2112,4347],[4200,4800,3720,4095]]]
MUG_FRONT = [[574,397,1557,1518],[".../mug-front.png"],[[0,0,37,62],[4200,0,3642,28],[0,4800,30,4744],[4200,4800,3670,4686]]]
MUG_MAIN = [[968,1052,968,1716],[".../mug-main.png"],[[0,0,360,774],[4200,0,2720,0],[0,4800,605,4539],[4200,4800,2860,3494]]]
MUGS = [MUG_SIDE,MUG_FRONT,MUG_MAIN]
i = 0
for item in MUGS:
    coor = []
    for coor_set in item[2]:
        for item in coor_set:
            coor += item
    print coor
    file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(item[1]).read())
    mug_overlay = Image.open(item[1]).convert("RGBA")
    canvas = Image.new('RGB', (2000,2000), (255,255,255))

    ShepardsDistortion = DistortImageMethod(14)
    MagickWandGenesis()
    wand = NewMagickWand()
    MagickReadImage(wand,file)
    MagickDistortImage(wand,ShepardsDistortion, len(coor), coor, False)
    #RESIZE IMAGE HERE, PRE-SAVING
    MagickWriteImage(wand,location+"mug_warp_temp.png")

    design_warped = Image.open(location+"mug_warp_temp.png").convert("RGBA")
    width = item[0][2] - item[0][0]
    height = item[0][3] - item[0][1]

    design_warped = design_warped.resize( (width,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    #replace later

    canvas.paste(design_warped, (item[0][0],item[0][1]), mask=design_warped)
    canvas.paste(mug_overlay, mask=mug_overlay)
    if item[1][-8:] == "main.png":
        print "paste corner art"
    canvas.save(location+"mugtest_"+i+".png")
    i=i+1
```

Needless to say, if there's an easier way to bend an image around a cylinder via a Python script, that would be cool too. :p

Comment: Shepard's warp is not what you want. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#displace_cylinder. Or you could call my unix bash shell script, cylinder warp, from python. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderwarp/index.php

Comment: @fmw42 Hi, sorry for the delay, SO didn't light up my inbox. This is really useful! Can I get any help with importing the module? Thanks!

Comment: `@Neff ` Sorry, I am not much of a python scripter. I would suggest you use the python subprocess command to call my bash unix shell script. Or work from the imagemagick link to display_cylinder and try to convert those Imagemagick commands to python or use PythonMagick. My script is way too complex to try to convert to python, at least for me.

Comment: @fmw42 I'm trying to make the bulk of this project in Python so that it's all easy for me to access when I link all the pieces together. Your help has been invaluable, though!